# undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass when calling errors for validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to do the [validation part](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-some-validation), but when I use:

```
<% @admin_email.errors.any? %>
```

It show: undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass.`I check some other guides and answers, they advice to create a 'new' method but it doesn`t help.

My view:

```
<div>
            <%= link_to (t(:show_all_emails) + " (#{AdminEmail.count})"), email_list_path, class: 'devise-link' %>

            <%= form_with(url: send_mails_path) do |f| %>
              <% if @admin_email.errors.any? %>
                <% @admin_email.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                  <div class="alert"><%= msg %></div>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
              <div class="field">
                <%= label_tag t(:delivery_subject) %><br>
                <%= text_field_tag :delivery_subject, '', class: 'form-control' %>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <%= label_tag t(:delivery_text) %><br>
                <%= text_area_tag :delivery_text, '', class: 'form-control' %>
              </div>
              <br>
              <%= f.submit t(:submit_button), class: 'btn btn-primary devise-button' %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
```

My controller:

```
class AdministrationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_admin!, only: %i[administration send_mails new]

  def administration
    @mode = 'administration'
    @topics = Topic.all
    @users = User.all.reject{|user| user.user_role == 'admin'}
    @banned_users = @users.select{|user| user.banned?}
    @active_users = @users.select{|user| user.confirmed?} - @banned_users
    @inactive_users = @users.select{|user| !user.confirmed?} - @banned_users
  end

  def email_list
    @admin_emails = AdminEmail.all
  end

  def new
    @admin_email = AdminEmail.new
  end

  def update

  end

  def activate_user
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @user&.update_attribute(:banned, false)
    redirect_to administration_path
  end

  def deactivate_user
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @user&.update_attribute(:banned, true)
    redirect_to administration_path
  end

  def send_mails
    @admin_email = AdminEmail.create(text: params[:delivery_text], subject: params[:delivery_subject])
    Delayed::Job.enqueue MailerJob.new(params[:delivery_text], params[:delivery_subject])
    if (@admin_email.save)
      redirect_to email_list_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

end
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which view file is this? I mean for which action?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't declared **@post** in your controller. It's not present in any action of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

This type of errors are very common. Check wherever you are finding @post. If value of @post is nil then your statement   "<% @post.errors.any? %>". will throw this error.